# How can I install a Steam game using the game installer exe?

Tags: steam

I bought cook serve delicious a while ago from their website before I got steam. Now that I have steam installed, I'd like to have cook serve delicious in my library; however obviously I don't want to have to buy the game again. I have the original installer .exe file that I downloaded when I bought the game. Is there any way I can use this to install my game into my steam library so it can receive the full benefits that steam provides (automatic updates etc.)?

Comment: Since this is an indie team, it might be possible to just email them and explain the situation (along with proof of purchase), and ask for a Steam key.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Unfortunately not.** Although you can add a shortcut to the game on Steam and the Steam overlay will even show up, that still doesn't do much and it's still a *non-Steam* game.

However, chances are that you may have received a redeemable Steam code with your order, or that you may have one accessible somewhere with your purchase.

Comment: You *can* still use a subset of steam functionality like the steam overlay and streaming/broadcasting functionality with non-steam games.

Comment: Do note that things like achievements will not be counted when playing a Steam game installed from other means.